# base64 to hex in python 2.7 strange symbols using b64decode()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to decode base64 string to hex. For example:
/6o= (base64) to FFAA (hex)
I'm trying:

```
encoded="/6o="
print base64.decodestring(encoded)
```

It gives me: ��

If I do:

```
encoded="/6o="
print base64.b64decode(string)
```

Result is the same ��

Using binascii.hexlify():

```
string="/6o="
printbinascii.hexlify(string)
```

Result is 2f366f3d, which is not FFAA, as I need.
Using `string.decode('hex')`:

```
string="/6o="
print string.decode('hex')
```

Result - error `TypeError: Non-hexadecimal digit found`

Using [this service](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/base64.php?lang=en) I can decode my base64 string properly.
How can I decode base64 to base16?

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
Oleg Somov

Comment: Base64 encoding is used to represent binary data as text, so if you are decoding base64 string you expect to get ASCII characters I guess, not hex values. So you should try to convert base64.decodestring(encoded) to hex

Comment: ... Did you try doing both?

Comment: @Semant1ka thank you for an answer, I'll try that in an hour. So you think I need to do binascii.hexlify(base64.decodestring(string))?

Comment: @OlegSomov I've found a more accurate solution, see answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import base64
import codecs

encoded="/6o="
decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
b_string = codecs.encode(decoded, 'hex')
print(b_string.decode('utf-8').upper())
```

it will give you:

FFAA

This works both for Python 2.7 and Python 3.6.

Comment: Print with brackets doesn't necessarily mean python 3. For one, you can import the python 3 `print` command in python 2 with `from __future__ import print_function`. And in the same way that `(a)` is the same as `a`, `print(a)` is interpreted as `print a`.

Comment: @Reti43 thank you for the note, I didn't know about that

Comment: @Semant1ka I was just changing from python 3 to python 2.7 couple times, so left brackets to try code in both versions. Thank you for the answer, it works as I needed!(BTW: It was your "-1"?) )

Comment: @Oleg Somov you're welcome. Nope, that wasn't me, I can't see why your question was downvoted

Answer (score 3):

### The solution.

Actually, the following 3 methods work in Python 2.7:

```
b64 = "/6o="

#1
b16 = b64.decode('base64')
print repr(b16) # '\xff\xaa'

import base64

#2
b16 = base64.b64decode(b64)
print repr(b16) # '\xff\xaa'

#3
b16 = base64.decodestring(b64)
print repr(b16) # '\xff\xaa'
```

With them you'll get bytes in their hex-representation.
Then if it's needed, you can convert bytes to the desired output, for example:

```
print b16.encode('hex').upper() # 'FFAA'
```

But be aware - now it's other bytes:

```
print 'FFAA' == '\xff\xaa' # False
```

---

**Summarizing**, the fastest solution (*no imports needed*):

```
b64 = "/6o="
print b64.decode('base64').encode('hex').upper() # 'FFAA'
```

---

### Understanding the problem.

Note, that I used **repr()** in printouts.

Your problem is caused by the fact that when we use the `print`-statement with  `str`-type (which is in fact bytes in 2.7),
in the first place Python is trying to decode it to `unicode`-type using the encoding which depends on environment.

For example, here is the difference in decoding bytes in my Ubuntu and Win10 terminals respectively:

[image]

The reason for such behavior is that `'\xff\xaa'` is not a valid `UTF-8` byte-sequence, so it can't be decoded to characters with this encoding. In this case, the errors are replaced by a symbol �.
At the same time, these bytes are valid in `cp1251` and we can see the result of decoding.

---

By the way, you can get the �-result you described in the question with the following expression:

```
print unicode('\xff\xaa', 'utf-8', errors='replace')
```

The output: ��

As far as I understand that is exactly what Python does in your case.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I knew that the problem somewhere in decoding bytes when printing, but I didn't know what is exactly wrong. Your explanation is quite clear. Spasibo!